# TypeScript assign enum value to another enum value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, vue.js

I have a method called `saveTask`

```
type Task = string;
enum Priority {
  Low = "Low",
  Medium = "Medium",
  High = "High",
}
enum Label {
  Low = "Low",
  Med = "Med",
  High = "High",
}
interface Item {
  task: Task;
  priority: Priority;
}

 const saveTask = ({ task, priority }: Item) => {
    const id = Date.now();
    let label: Label;
    if (priority === "Medium") {
      label = Label.Med;
    } else {
      label = priority;
    }
    // dispatch(addItem({ task, priority, id, isActive: true, label }));
    // handleClose();
  };
```

In here `priority is a value which is equal to "Low", "Medium" or "High"
Based on the priority I create an additional property called a label. The label could be "Low", "Medium" or "High"

In the else block when I try to say

> label = priority

This gives me an error

[image]

How could I fix this issue?

Comment: enums are one of the few things that TypeScript treats like *nominal types*, meaning you can't just assign one to another.  If you are using them this way, then you don't really want enums.  How about just some [strongly typed `const`s](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#objects-vs-enums) like [this code](https://tsplay.dev/Na0RBw)?  Does that work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the cleanest design, but you can force the compiler's hand:

```
type Task = string;

enum Priority {
  Low = "Low",
  Medium = "Medium",
  High = "High",
}

enum Label {
  Low = "Low",
  Med = "Med",
  High = "High",
}

interface Item {
  task: Task;
  priority: Priority;
}

 const saveTask = ({ task, priority }: Item) => {
    const id = Date.now();
    let label: Label;
    
    if (priority === Priority.Medium) {
      label = Label.Med;
    } else {
      label = Label[Priority[priority] as keyof typeof Label];
    }

    console.log(label);
};

saveTask({task: 'test', priority: Priority.Low}); // "Low"
saveTask({task: 'test', priority: Priority.Medium}); // "Med"
saveTask({task: 'test', priority: Priority.High}); // "High"
```